# projectVector results not between -1 and 1 (three.js)

Tags: three.js, webgl

Note: code below updated with WestLangley's fix.

I've tried several examples of projecting from 3D to 2D.  However, when I try to use projectVector the result is not between -1 and 1, and so when I multiply by my window's width/height I get extravagantly large numbers (much larger than my screen resolution).  Hoping that my problem is something simple.  I'm using three.min.js r56, and my inner window dimensions are 1366x418.

The code below yields a projected (x,y) of: (-7.874704599380493,-13.403168320655823) for the 3D point (1200,625,100).  I know I still need to multiple this result by something like half my window height and width, but the resulting (x,y) in pixels is way off the screen.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="three.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='container'></canvas>

<script>

    /// GLOBAL VARIABLES
    var camera, scene, renderer, container, projector;

    init();

    function toXYCoord (object) {
        var vector = projector.projectVector(object.position.clone(), camera);
        return vector;
    }

    /// INIT
    function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 20000 );
        scene.add(camera);
        camera.position.set(0,-1500,1500);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        camera.updateMatrixWorld();     ///////////////// THIS IS THE FIX
        projector = new THREE.Projector();

        // sphere   
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 32, 16 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 }) );
        sphere.position.set(1200,625,100);
        scene.add(sphere);

        container = document.getElementById('container');
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: container, antialias:true } );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        var testVector = toXYCoord(sphere);

        console.log(window.innerWidth + "x" + window.innerHeight);
        console.log("Got: (" + testVector.x + "," + testVector.y + ")");

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The renderer does some calculations for you that are normally done in the render loop.

They are not being done in your case because you have placed your single call to `render()` as the last line of your script.

You need to place the following line after `camera.lookAt()`:

```
camera.updateMatrixWorld();
```

Alternatively, you can move your

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

call so it occurs before your call to your `toXYCoord()` function.